# Beamer custom breakable box

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, mdframed

In this case I need a breakable for custom example that I could break part of contents and move to next frame.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most,many,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mdframed} % default settin
\mdfsetup{
skipabove =4pt, skipbelow =4pt,
innerlinewidth=4pt,outerlinewidth=4pt,
middlelinewidth=4pt,
leftline = false, topline = false,
rightline=false,bottomline=false}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\definecolor{mytheoremfr}{HTML}{00007B}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,hooks}

\makeatletter

\define@key{beamerframe}{s}[true]{% stretch
  \beamer@frametopskip=4pt\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=4pt plus 0.001fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
   \centering
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\beamer@leftmargin-\beamer@rightmargin\relax}
    % \vspace{-4ex}
   \centering
   \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} \vskip -2pt
   \usebeamerfont{footline}%
   \usebeamercolor{footline}%
   % \hfill\insertpagenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
   \hfill\insertpagenumber
   \hfill%
   \llap{\insertframenavigationsymbol\insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol}\par
   \end{minipage}\vskip4pt
}
\makeatother

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{myExample}{Ex}
{%
         colback= black!7
        ,enhanced
        ,breakable
    ,colframe = black!65
    ,coltitle = black!100
    ,boxrule = 1pt
    % ,sharp corners 
    ,detach title
    ,before upper=\tcbtitle\par\smallskip
    ,fonttitle = \bfseries
    ,description font = \mdseries
    ,separator sign none
    ,description delimiters parenthesis
}{ex}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

     
    % FIRST CASE
    \begin{frame}[s]
        \begin{myExample}{Example}{}
        \lipsum[1-2]
        \end{myExample}
    \end{frame}

    % SECOND CASE
    \begin{frame}[s]
        \begin{mdframed}
        \begin{myExample}{Example}{}
        \lipsum[1-2]
        \end{myExample}
    \end{mdframed}
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

**First case:**

I use this construction, so I have the required margins for me, as well as the ability to manage text on one slide, insert pictures and before the selected custom environment, no empty slides appear, however, the content does not correctly transfer to the next frame

[image]

**Second case:**
In this case I have no  required margins for me, before the selected custom environment, I have empty slides appear, but the content does correctly transfer to the next frame except that, for example, for frame 5 there is no top padding, and for frame 6, the top padding is not equal to the bottom padding of frame 5.

[image]

***My trouble:*** *Is it possible to keep the margins and alignment as for the first case, but it would work to transfer the content to the tcolorbox, and at the same time, the top indent for the next frame would be equal to the bottom indent for the previous one, when using `mdframed` ?*

Comment: You could split the tcolorbox across multiple page with a) the `allowframebreaks` option and b) using `\framebreak` at a suitable place inside the box (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/692584/36296 for an example). For an automatic approach, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/509263/36296 . A frame with fixed top and bottom margin really needs some stretchable material inside it.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

If I use `\framebreak` with  `allowframebreaks` I get empty previous frame, before my custom enviroment.  tex.stackexchange.com/a/509263/36296  -- automatic approach move fragments in such a way that some of the letters, for example, in a line are split in such a way that half is related to the previous slide, the rest to the next ... I see this post on stack, but it is not correct work with setted custom styles block...

Comment: If you get an empty page before the tcolorbox, than your first part of the box is too tall to fit on the frame. Try to use `\framebreak` earlier

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZVsWwW5v seems to break fine without extra page https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUAhB.png

Comment: It really is preferable to just make separate boxes for Beamer. Certainly `\allowframebreaks` should be avoided in this kind of case. (I use it for bibliographies, but that's about it.) But what I'd do is put it on one slide in a single `frame` and use either `overprint` or whatever-the-other-one-is-called, so it doesn't jump at the transition. (This is pretty much equivalent to keeping the padding the same, I think, but the whole box will stay the same size, regardless of the size of content.) Even if you need all of it in `handout` mode, this works well. You just have to force it a bit.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

enlarge top at break by=0.5cm -- is working solution for problem, in this case. So, I should manually catch places and use `\framebreak`, but, perhaps this is the concept of this  `beamer` document class, in order to change the content within one slide, and set the boundaries of the text break yourself. Thanks a lot for solution!!!

Comment: @Alex The concept of beamer is to use overlays and not framebreaks to distribute content over multiple slides. [As said before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694108/how-to-align-text-vertically-in-beamer-frame#comment1723036_694113) using framebreaks is evil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually split the tcolorbox using `\framebreak`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most,many,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mdframed} % default settin
\mdfsetup{
skipabove =4pt, skipbelow =4pt,
innerlinewidth=4pt,outerlinewidth=4pt,
middlelinewidth=4pt,
leftline = false, topline = false,
rightline=false,bottomline=false}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\definecolor{mytheoremfr}{HTML}{00007B}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems,skins,hooks}

\makeatletter

\define@key{beamerframe}{s}[true]{% stretch
  \beamer@frametopskip=4pt\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=4pt plus 0.001fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
   \centering
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\beamer@leftmargin-\beamer@rightmargin\relax}
    % \vspace{-4ex}
   \centering
   \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} \vskip -2pt
   \usebeamerfont{footline}%
   \usebeamercolor{footline}%
   % \hfill\insertpagenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
   \hfill\insertpagenumber
   \hfill%
   \llap{\insertframenavigationsymbol\insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol}\par
   \end{minipage}\vskip4pt
}
\makeatother

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{myExample}{Ex}
{%
         colback= black!7
        ,enhanced
        ,breakable
    ,colframe = black!65
    ,coltitle = black!100
    ,boxrule = 1pt
    % ,sharp corners 
    ,detach title
    ,before upper=\tcbtitle\par\smallskip
    ,fonttitle = \bfseries
    ,description font = \mdseries
    ,separator sign none
    ,description delimiters parenthesis,
    enlarge top at break by=0.5cm
}{ex}


\begin{document}

    % FIRST CASE
    \begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
        \begin{myExample}{Example}{}
        \lipsum[2]
        \framebreak
        \lipsum[2]
        \end{myExample}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]